# How to insert multiple values into specific treeview columns?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a database returning the total of several column and I am trying to display it in a treeview. If I do

```
for i in backend2.calc_total()[0]:
    treeviewtotal.insert("", END, values=i)
```

I get

[image]

which is not what i want as i want everything to start from "food" column onwards. I cant make date a iid as i already have an iid that I am referencing to my database.

If I do

```
list2 = ['Date', 'Food', 'Transport', 'Insurance', 'Installments', 'Others']
for i in range(len(backend2.calc_total()[0][0])):
     treeviewtotal.insert("", 0, list2[i+1], values=backend2.calc_total()[0][0][i])
```

I get this

[image]

instead, all the totals get stacked into 1 column (which is scrollable).

Any way to achieve my aim of allocating the respective totals to the respective column in a same row? Thanks!

Comment: maybe you shoud use column number `i` instead of 0 (zero) in `insert(..., i+1, ...)`. Or use `END` and first insert empty string which will be insterd as `Date`

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the first attempt, the following solves the problem:

```
for i in backend2.calc_total()[0]:
        treeviewtotal.insert("", END, values=([], *i))
```

`values=` takes in a list. Therefore we add an empty space by using `[]`, but since `i` itself is already a list, we need to "flatten out" the list by doing `*i`.

Please correct me if I used any parts of the code wrongly. Still trying to learn =)